# VB6 MSXML2 "The host name in the certificate is invalid or does not match."

Tags: vb6

This code works on 2 different WIN7 machines but fails on 2 different XP machines:

Public Function GetLocationTemperature(urlString As String, ByRef kPa as Single) As Single

On Error GoTo errHandler

```
Dim website As Object
Set website = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")

'website.setOption(2) = (website.getOption(2) = SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_ALL_SERVER_ERRORS

Call website.open("GET", urlString, False)
Call website.send("")
........
```

In XP Runtime the website.send reports an Error "The host name in the certificate is invalid or does not match"

SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_ALL_SERVER_ERRORS is not required in WIN7 and does not help in XP.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

FIXED with website.setOption 2, 13056, don't know why, but I do not care.

Comment: From MSDN: `SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_ALL_SERVER_ERRORS = 13056`

Comment: Hi, can you please post how you used this code?